# How to add userid parameter to payload of jwt when generate access token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt

How can I add the `userId` parameter to the payload of `jwt` when I generate an access token?

I work on `asp.net core 2.2` and I need to add the `userId` parameter to the payload of ***generate access token*** then generate a result as JSON.

```
  public string GenerateTokens(string userId)
            {    
                var Claims = new Claim[]
                         {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,userId)
                         };
                var signingkey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is secret phrase"));
                var SigningCredntials = new SigningCredentials(signingkey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                var Jwt = new JwtSecurityToken();

                return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(Jwt);
            }
```

Comment: are there are any thing not clear

Answer (score 0):

You should set claims when initializing the `JwtSecurityToken` instance :

```
var Claims = new Claim[]
{
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,"userid")
     //your other claims
};
var signingkey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is secret phrase"));
var SigningCredntials = new SigningCredentials(signingkey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
var Jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(claims:Claims,signingCredentials:SigningCredntials);

return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(Jwt);
```

The constructor function of `JwtSecurityToken` which also can set the `issue`,`audience`, `expires`..

```
public JwtSecurityToken(string issuer = null, string audience = null, IEnumerable<Claim> claims = null, DateTime? notBefore = null, DateTime? expires = null, SigningCredentials signingCredentials = null);
```

Comment: and what about adding user id  i see that user id not exist on function above user id parameters have values

Comment: so that i need to add userid how to do please ?

Comment: this is good thing but what this this meaning  JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub

Comment: Any error problem ? If the reply helps, please consider mark as answer .